# Seamless integrated encryption for Windows that also encrypts the file names?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, efs

I recently discovered about the EFS (Encrypting File System) feature on Windows and so far I liked what it had to offer; with just a few clicks the file(s) are encrypted and aren't accessible even when using a Linux live USB to access the file system outside of Windows.

However, it has one downside which is that the file names are not encrypted. So while the contents might be inaccessible, even a remotely descriptive file name would give a hint as to what the file could be.

Now I'm looking for a way to be able to do what EFS does with the additional step that when the file is viewed from outside of Windows, the file name is unrecognizable. I could be wrong but I think that's what BitLocker does except it encrypts the whole drive which is **not** what I want. I just want it to apply to a handful of folders/files.

I've considered solutions like VeraCrypt but that goes over my initial point of it being seamlessly integrated into Windows when I have to mount a separate drive from a file instead of just right clicking a folder anywhere on the system and not worry about passwords or certificates as long as I'm logged in to my user account.

Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: “I just want it to apply to a handful of folders/files.” - This doesn’t exist. There are only two solutions on Windows. EFS which encrypts a folder containing files are FDE which encrypts the entire disk. There isn’t a software package that will just encrypt file names.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. "Seamlessly integrated" practically requires support to be built into the filesystem (like EFS is), and such feature is not built into Windows; what EFS does is all you have.

With any kind of reasonably modern CPU, I'd suggest just using BitLocker for the entire disk regardless.

(It is also possible to use BitLocker with VHD/VHDX disk images, making it work similarly to VeraCrypt but without the need for any external tools or drivers.)

Comment: I was thinking it could work like how some syncing apps can modify how a file works and some even have the capability to make it seem like you're accessing the file locally when in reality it's being streamed from the cloud in the background. If they could implement that, I thought the sky's the limit

Comment: They can make that happen for a _file's_ contents, but not so much for a directory's contents (i.e. not for filenames). The placeholders created by OneDrive or Dropbox actually exist on disk (in the form of reparse points) with their real names in their "real" location; the cloud sync is only triggered after opening an existing reparse point.

Comment: Though, recent Windows does have a feature called "ProjFS" which could virtualize a directory, but actually using it (if there were any encryption programs using it) would still be similar to mounting and unmounting a disk volume.